# Find how many terms there are in this geometric sequence $-1, 2, -4, 8, ..., -16777216$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms

> Find how many terms there are in this geometric sequence:
>
> $-1, 2, -4, 8, ..., -16777216$

My attempt:

$a_k=a.r^{k-1}$

And in this sequence:

$a=-1$, $r=-2$

So

$a_k=(-1){(-2)}^{k-1}$

$-16777216=(-1){(-2)}^{k-1}$

$16777216={(-2)}^{k-1}$

$log(16777216)=log({(-2)}^{k-1})$

$log(16777216)=(k-1)log{(-2)}$

$k-1={{log(16777216)} \over {log{(-2)}}}$

But $-2$ is negative, and logarithm not defined for negative numbers?,
So what can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: The sequence is $(-1)^{k+1} 2^k$ for k starting at 0. You should just ignore the fact that the negatives and positives flip every term and calculate $log_2(16777216)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Since the sign is causing you trouble, get rid of it. The number of terms in this sequence is the same as the number of terms in the sequence
$$1,2,4,8,...,16777216
$$

Comment: Oh yeah you are right, Thank you so so so much, so the answer is $25$ :).

Answer (score 1):

It is:
$$-1,2,-4,8,...,(-1)\cdot 2^{24}$$

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, there are $25$ terms.

Answer (score 1):

$-16777216=(-1){(-2)}^{k-1}={(-1)}^k2^{k-1}=-2^{k-1}$ (exponent can't be negative so minus has to come from -1)

Comment: You are always welcome!

Answer (score 1):

To use logarithms, take the absolute values of the terms.  Then you have

$|-1|×|-2|^{k-1}=|-16777216|$

$1×2^{k-1}=16777216$

where all numbers are positive and the logarithms can be manipulated without trouble.  When you find $k$ you must check against the original equation with the negative signs included to verify that the proposed solution is valid.